# Spring 4 and compiling with jdk 7

Tags: java, spring

We update to spring 4 for a couple of reasons, but needed to remain on jdk 7 for the time being (too close to release!).  All was fine and good until I started using PropertySource.  This class uses the Repeatable annotation which is a java 8 class... and suddenly we fail to compile, missing class.

We use -Werror as part of our compiling process and could turn that off, but that seems like the nuclear option.  Is there any other mechanism to get javac working again without killing off all warnings-as-compilation-failures?

Comment: can you elaborate on the versions of Spring you are using? I am running a 4.0.6 version app with JDK 1.7 update 55 and it works fine; including property source annotation

Comment: Also running 4.0.6 with java build 40.  Not sure how you're escaping it!  You're compiling with -Werror?

Comment: I have a Spring MVC application with Gradle build in STS, and the project build path points to JDK 1.7 as alternate JRE

Comment: I actually have two different build systems (temporary), one being ant, the other a home-grown builder that handles c++ as well as java.  Both cough and die with the -Werror flag set on the javac compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, thats an issue with Spring 4 and jdk 7. Can you try the following..

Instead of using annotation like...

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/datasource.properties")
```

use...

```
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:/datasource.properties")})
```

This link describes the solution in more depth...

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/how-to-using-propertysource-annotation-in-spring-4-with-java-7.html